# Gradle not pulling .jar from repository

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've modified the module gradle.build file by adding the "repositories" and "dependencies" lines shown below.  the build returns successful, but when i check the /libs, the 1.2.0 version of the jar is not there and i have "cannot resolve symbol" errors throughout the java code. The build works fine with the achartengine-1.1.0.jar that is in /libs so it seems to be a problem with how gradle accesses (copy or temp) the achartengine-1.2.0.jar for the build (i'm new to Gradle).

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 8
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo"
        minSdkVersion 4
        targetSdkVersion 7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
/*dependencies {
    compile files('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
}*/
repositories {
    maven {url 'https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.2.0/'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/achartengine-1.2.0.jar')
}
/*<dependency>
  <groupId>org.achartengine</groupId>
<artifactId>achartengine</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>*/
```

Answer (score 1):

> but when i check the /libs, the 1.2.0 version of the jar is not there

Unless you manually put it there, it's not going to be there.

If you are trying to get it from the Maven repo, you need to replace:

```
compile files('libs/achartengine-1.2.0.jar')
```

with:

```
compile 'org.achartengine:achartengine:1.2.0'
```

That still will not put anything in `libs/`, but it will download the artifact and add it to your build process by another means.

Comment: I just noticed that "maven" was added to the gradle.build automagically.  the original repo reference was extracted from a maven script:
    `<repository>
      <id>achartengine</id>
      <name>Public AChartEngine repository</name>
      <url>https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/</url>
    </repository>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.achartengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>achartengine</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>`

Comment: @robWDC: That does not change my recommendation. You will see that the `<dependency>` element in your Maven script equates to the `compile` statement in my answer.

Comment: tried your recommendation.  I'm getting "Failed to find: org...:1.2.0".  Thanks for the recommendations and help.  See my answer below.  Based on the referenced article, it looks like i need to setup a cloudbees.com account.

Comment: @robWDC: That's bizarre. I would agree with your assessment that manual dependency management may be a better option in this case.